# Mysql query: Find least used words

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of words used in the title of articles. I want to find which words which are used the least in the set or article titles.

**Example:**

Titles:

```
"Congressman Joey of Texas does not sign bill C1234."
"The pretty blue bird flies at night in Texas."
"Congressman Bob of Arizona is the signs bill C1234."
```

The table would contain the following.

*Table WORDS_LIST*

```
----------------------------------------------------
| INDEX ID | WORD                     | ARTICLE ID |
----------------------------------------------------
| 1        | CONGRESSMAN              | 1234       |
| 2        | JOEY                     | 1234       |
| 3        | SIGN                     | 1234       |
| 4        | BILL                     | 1234       |
| 5        | C1234                    | 1234       |    
| 6        | TEXAS                    | 1234       |
| 7        | PRETTY                   | 1235       |
| 8        | BLUE                     | 1245       |
| 9        | BIRD                     | 1245       |
| 10       | FLIES                    | 1245       |
| 11       | NIGHT                    | 1245       |
| 12       | TEXAS                    | 1245       |
| 13       | CONGRESSMAN              | 1246       |
| 14       | BOB                      | 1246       |
| 15       | ARIZONA                  | 1246       |
| 16       | SIGNS                    | 1246       |
| 17       | BILL                     | 1246       |
| 18       | C1234                    | 1246       |
----------------------------------------------------
```

In this case, the words "pretty,blue, flies, night" would be the used in the least number of articles.

I would appreciate any ideas on how to best create this query. So far below is what I started with. I can also write something in PHP but figured a query would be faster.

```
SELECT distinct a1.`word`, count(a1.`word`)
FROM mmdb.words_list a1
JOIN mmdb.words_list b1 
ON a1.id = b1.id AND
upper(a1.word) = upper(b1.word)
where date(a1.`publish_date`) = '2017-06-09'
group by `word`
order by count(a1.`word`);
```

Comment: So what's wrong with the query you have? Is it not returning what you want? Can you show an example of what it returns?

Comment: You don't need `DISTINCT`. `GROUP BY` guarantees that it will be distinct.

Comment: Why are you joining the table to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It's a bit more simple and should return the correct results:

```
SELECT `WORD`,
    COUNT(*) as `num_articles`
FROM `WORDS_LIST`
WHERE date(`publish_date`) = '2017-06-09'
GROUP BY `WORD`
ORDER BY COUNT(*) ASC;
```

Comment: he wants the *least* used words, so it should be `ASC`.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, same results as my original query but this confirms that I was doing it correct and I am halfway there.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see why a self-join is necessary.  Just do something like this:

```
select wl.word, count(*)
from mmdb.words_list wl
where date(wl.`publish_date`) = '2017-06-09'
group by wl.word
order by count(*);
```

You can add a `limit` to get a fixed number of words.  If `publish_date` is already a date, you should do the comparison as:

```
where publish_date = '2017-06-09'
```

If it has a time component:

```
where publish_date >= '2017-06-09' and publish_date < '2017-06-10'
```

This expression allows MySQL to use an index.